# Trying to create imageView when click the button

Tags: android, android-imageview, onclicklistener

I am trying to create ImageView when I click the button.I don't know why when I am creating it I get the error on new Image.

the code I am working is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button save;

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView image = new ImageView(activity_main,this);
            RelativeLayout mylayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.element_wall);
            mylayout.addView(image);

        }
    });
```

As I sayd I am getting error on this line: 
                ImageView image = new ImageView(activity_main,this);
I have tryed to put only this but not working, I am using activity_main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that you posted wrong or right or typing mistake but according to your code it should be

```
 ImageView image = new ImageView(activity_main,this);
```

to

```
 ImageView image = new ImageView(activity_main.this);
```

also you can use

```
 image.setImageResource(R.drawable.element_wall);
```

instead of

```
 image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.element_wall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the constructor of ImageView [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Your code should look like:

```
  ImageView image = new ImageView(<YourActivityClass>.this);
```