# How to add new imageView On button clicked

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two menu buttons in which I click one create new Text View and other add sticker from already add drawable section I created a new button on which I click first take me to gallery from where I select Image then I can add Then to activity .
Every time I click it should add new Sticker Image View.

Main Activity File

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_add_sticker) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, StickerSelectActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_STICKER_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_add_text) {
            addTextSticker();
        }else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.main_add_image){



        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void addTextSticker() {
        TextLayer textLayer = createTextLayer();
        TextEntity textEntity = new TextEntity(textLayer, motionView.getWidth(),
                motionView.getHeight(), fontProvider);
        motionView.addEntityAndPosition(textEntity);

        // move text sticker up so that its not hidden under keyboard
        PointF center = textEntity.absoluteCenter();
        center.y = center.y * 0.5F;
        textEntity.moveCenterTo(center);

        // redraw
        motionView.invalidate();

        startTextEntityEditing();
    }

    private TextLayer createTextLayer() {
        TextLayer textLayer = new TextLayer();
        Font font = new Font();

        font.setColor(TextLayer.Limits.INITIAL_FONT_COLOR);
        font.setSize(TextLayer.Limits.INITIAL_FONT_SIZE);
        font.setTypeface(fontProvider.getDefaultFontName());

        textLayer.setFont(font);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            textLayer.setText("Hello, world :))");
        }

        return textLayer;
    }
```

XML Of main_menu

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/main_add_sticker"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:title="@string/add_sticker"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_add_text"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_text"
        android:title="@string/add_text"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_add_image"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_text"
        android:title="@string/add_image"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to create imageView when click the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805711/trying-to-create-imageview-when-click-the-button)

Answer (score 0):

Try `setVisible()`. Create a `ImageView` and add attribute `ImageView.setVisible(false)`. From the java code you can apply, `ImageView.setVisible(true)`.

Comment: no Bro I want to create new Sticker Image View every time I click it should add new Image Sticker there . means multiple images creation from gallery from one button

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamically

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
```

> See [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView) to modify coordinates